# How to print memory addresses of Ruby instruction?

Tags: ruby, memory, bytecode, memory-address

I'm trying to print the bytecode instructions that Ruby interpreter generates as well as the memory addresses associated for each instruction.

I am aware of that I can use `RubyVM::InstructionSequence` to get the disassembled instruction sequence of a program, but it does not print memory addresses associated with. For example, all I get now is

```
0000 trace      8                                               (   1)
0002 trac       1                                               (   2)
0004 putself
0005 putstring  "hello, world"
0007 send       :puts, 1, nil, 8, <ic:0>
0013 trace      16                                              (   3)
0015 leave                                                      (   2)
```

But, I am looking for is additional info., such as

```
0x__MEM_ADDRESS__ putstring  "hello, world"
```

Or, something like that. My main point is, again, is to get the memory address of each instruction.

Can anyone direct me to the place where I can get that information? Or, is it not possible? If that's the case, I'm happy to know that as well rather than putting too much effort to the question that has no answer to it.

Appreciate all your help.

Comment: I don't think it's actually possible.
The interesting you can do is output the iseq to binary (which is actually loadable in some conditions) so that's where you'll be able to see real opcode.

Comment: @user11659763 Thank you for your reply. That's an interesting approach. I will try it out. Thank you, again.